# how to check app download and installation

Tags: android

I am planning to create a kinda reward app in android.
I am going to list up the game apps on my app. 
When the user download/install one of apps on the list, the use will get some point for quid pro quo.

What is the best way to check the completion of download and installation? 
Since the user is redirected to PlayStore to download when he/she clicks on the apps, I think that every apps on the list of my app, should put some codes (INTENT) to pass API URL call with App ID and User Device Info etc.

Any advice will be really appreciated.

Comment: there is a method that will fetch all the installed games or app on device filtering by the packagename. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to know if an application has been installed is via the `PackageManager`

This is something you could do in an `AsyncTask` as this is a bit slow based on number of applications present in the device.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); 
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    for (i = 0; i < packages.size(); i++) {
        if (packageInfo.packageName.compareToIgnoreCase("com.yourpackage") == 0) { 
            //Implies package is installed.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... ^^ I couldn't access stackoverflow yesterday. I thought it must be down for too much traffic or something.